# Php docx modification

Tags: php, ms-word

I'm looking to preserve the formatting of the document. Any changes to the original document will be highlighted In red color. This will saved as another document.

So far I have extracted raw text from a docx file. I can make a function that finds the modified parts. But is there any way I can highlight the changed/added text to the original document to red color.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but you'll need to backtrack a bit and work on the *parsed* XML, not the raw text. Also you're only going to be able to identify a continuous string *with no intervening* markup (not strictly true, but the code gets very complex).

Answer (score 0):

no, not so easy! I tried and it's very hard to generate the right attributes values. Example, I can modify the XML files to insert an image into a document (word/document.xml, word/media/imageXX.jpg, word/_rels/document.xml.rels) but the problem is the value of the attributes!